# Reference path incorrect after move

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I moved a VS 2010 project to a new machine.

The new machine has a slightly different directory structure.

I have a dll I need to reference and I tried deleting it in Solution Explorer than adding it back in.

However, when I run the code I get an error that says "Directory not found" and it is pointing to the OLD path of my dll.

I have tried rebuilding solution.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you add some more detail? A picture of the error would be helpful.

Comment: The dll contains that old path.

Comment: YES I KNOW!!! How do I change that...

Comment: Why not you copy that dll into your project directory ??

Comment: I do, I point at it when adding the ref. It still points to the old path at runtime

Comment: Rebuild the dll in the current project.